# How to auto store using uploadcare javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadcare

I am using a tools uploadcare from ([uploadcare.com](https://uploadcare.com))

I read the documentation but I cannot find how can we `autostore` when using javascript api to after upload a file.

Is autostore feature only available on widget and REST api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com)'s `autostore` is covered [here](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/#autostore)

Basically you need to enable `autostore` in project's settings (it's on by default) and on the page where you use upload dialog. So you can have several pages that enable automatic storing and some that don't.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

Put the `UPLOADCARE_AUTOSTORE = true;` just like the `UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY = 'pk';`